# free web library for leaderboards / achievements

Tags: html5, leaderboards

I would like to know if there is any free leaderboard libraries for web games developed in HTML5/JS (as openfeint is for iPhone, Android)

I found this http://www.appmobi.com/, but it seems the leaderboard APIs which are in BETA is not free.

Answer (score 3):

Clay.io does this as well:

Info Page: http://clay.io/development-tools
Documentation: http://clay.io/docs/leaderboards

Basic implementation is:

```
var leaderboard = new Clay.Leaderboard( { id: 'some-id' } );
leaderboard.post( { score: 500 } ); // Post a score of 500
leaderboard.show(); // Show the list of high scores
```

Of course, it's very customizable - that's just what's required to get it going.

Answer (score 3):

There is a new open source initiative by the creators of Open Feint. It's called Open Kit (http://openkit.io/) and it's open and free as they come.

Answer (score 2):

I would point you to http://tapjs.com

Been thinking of implementing this on a project of mine. Haven't done a lot of research though. Have a look.

Answer (score 2):

I integrated playtomic framework with my project. Its very simple to use. Doc can be found at:
https://playtomic.com/api/html5

Answer (score 1):

i suggest for better leaderboard integration use ShepHertz App42 ..this is not free but 1 million call are free ,that is sufficient for starting app developers.
[leaderboard](http://api.shephertz.com/tutorial/Getting-Started/)

Comment: This does not answer the question, because the question is specifically about *free* libraries.